# Electron: Refreshing Issue with Show Method in Transparent Frameless Window

Tags: electron, hide, transparent

Electron Version
28.1.0.

What operating system are you using?
Windows

Operating System Version
window 11

What arch are you using?
x64

Last Known Working Electron version
No response

Actual Behavior
Actually, if I create a window with parameters like frame=false and transparent=true, when I call the hide method and then the show method again, there will be flickering, similar to page refresh.

This is written based on the code in the Quick Start document for Electron, which is basically the same as the official one. I just added keyboard shortcuts and window property settings

To make it easier for observation, I set the background color to white.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qh5qF.png)

In the video, I repeatedly press the shortcut keys for hide and show. Sometimes there is no flickering issue, but most of the time the window keeps flickering.

[See Github](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/40830)

I want to prevent flickering when calling the show method on a hidden window

Comment: Please read [ask] and **never**, ***ever*** post code as an image. Instead, create a [mcve] and post it as text. Please [edit] your question accordingly. But this isn't a question, this is a bug report you have already posted on GitHub. (At least it reads like a bug report; do you actually have a question concerning your code?) Bug reports are out of scope for Stack Overflow. Also, you can't embed videos here on Stack Overflow.